# UIWebView not calling loadRequest if called from tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, didselectrowatindexpath

I know, this question has already asked many times, but non helped me. So I want to fire loadRequest when a row in UITableView is touched. But for some reason, it don't work. When [webView loadRequest:request]; is been called, nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *bookmarkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:bookmarkString];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[myWebView1 loadRequest:request1];
urlField1.text = bookmarkString;
```

}

I have tried many different variations of this code, but nothing works. After debugging with breakpoints, everything will get called but nothing actually happens on the web view. Dismissing modal view controller works, but not the loadRequest. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I use Storyboard

Comment: Are you sure `myWebView1` is not nil? For example, you might've forgotten to connect an outlet in IB.

Comment: Everything works if I do the load request from somwhere else, like from UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to allocate the UIWebView and then make the call, even if you connected it from your xib

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(!myWebView1)
{
    myWebView1 = [UIWebView alloc]init];
}
        NSString *bookmarkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:bookmarkString];
        NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [myWebView1 loadRequest:request1];
        urlField1.text = bookmarkString;
    }
```

Comment: No effect... This is very strange. It works everywhere else but not here. I think I have assigned all delegates etc. Could there still be something I might have forgotten/I didn't know about?

Comment: I think just to test yourself, open a new project with just a uiwebview and see if the code above is working.

Comment: I can get it work it's been called on viewDidLoad and etc. or Did End Editing on UITextField. If this helps, I have my same view controller (GBViewController) on my two "actual" view controllers in my Storyboard file. On action, I load up another GBViewController view as form sheet which is the table view controller